# assign text values to selected subset in the attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing

I am using QGIS and I would like to generate a new string of text in the attribute table for a selected subset of features in a vector file. I cannot find an operator in the field calculator to perform this task.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't the "updated only selected features" option exactly what you want?

Comment: I was using the wrong syntax. I was typing "text" in the expression box which didn´t work and it took me a while to figure out that in QGIS you have to put 'text'. Thanks anyways